# Using regex to grab values from a multi-line string in python

Tags: python, regex

I've seen very similar posts on here but I can't seem to get any of them to work.

Here is my code

```
import re

regex='<item>
<obj1>grab1</obj1>
<obj2>text<obj2>
...
</item>'
pattern=re.compile(regex)
searchfile=open('data.dat')
filetext=searchfile.read()
text=re.findall(pattern,filetext)
print text
```

I've tried putting \n in so the string looks like

```
regex='<item>\n
<obj1>grab1</obj1>\n
<obj2>grab2<obj2>\n
...
</item>'
```

but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would expect a syntax error.  A python multiline string uses three double quotes as the delimiter.

Comment: You probably need to fix your regex, what are you trying to look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
import re

regex = '''<item>
<obj1>grab1</obj1>
<obj2>text<obj2>
...
</item>'''

pattern = re.compile(regex)

with open('data.dat') as searchfile:
    filetext = searchfile.read()
    text = pattern.findall(filetext)
    print text
```

Answer (score 0):

Multi-line strings use three single or double quotes as delimiters. No need to add `\n` to indicate a new line.

Your code will then become:

```
import re

regex='''<item>
<obj1>grab1</obj1>
<obj2>text</obj2>
</item>'''
pattern=re.compile(regex)
searchfile=open('data.dat')
filetext=searchfile.read()
text=re.findall(pattern,filetext)
print text
```

That said, there is likely another error on the third line of your regex: you forgot to close the `<obj2>` element.

And finally, if you want to parse XML documents, I wouldn't recommend using regular expressions. Instead, you may want to look at libraries such as lxml.

Consider the following document, `data.dat`:

```
<document>
<item>
<obj1>grab1</obj1>
<obj2>text</obj2>
</item>
<otheritem></otheritem>
<item>
  <obj1>grab1</obj1>
  <obj2>text</obj2>
</item>
</document>
```

Running the above python code, you will get:
`['<item>\n<obj1>grab1</obj1>\n<obj2>text</obj2>\n</item>']`

The second `<item>` was ignored, because of the indentation.